# Last element in ListView in RemoteViews is not fully visible in Android Widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to show list inside widgets with remoteviews. Scrolling is working fine but last element is not fully scrollable and not fully visible. But if I expand the widget fully it shows the last element.

In my code nothing pretty fancy, just assigning adapter in AppWidgetProvider.

```
this.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widgets_list, intent)
```

My widget_timetable.xml where widget ui stores:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/widget_body_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.AppWidget.AppWidget.Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*">
    <include layout="@layout/widget_timetable_title_region" />
    <include layout="@layout/widget_timetable_list_meetings" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/widgets_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
        tools:discard="@layout/unused2"
        tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
        tools:listitem="@layout/widget_item" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the video:

https://jumpshare.com/s/kWcJau9HW5rcsjGq96xw

[image]

Comment: Try using wrap-content for list view item, This might help the ListView to calculate its height based on the content. Still it doesn't help try setting bottom margin and check whether listview's bottom moving up or not. Check whether the views inside ListView layout has fixed size. If you could provide code for that too, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks man. Settings bottom margin for listview helped! post answer to this post, I will approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a fixed bottom margin for the ListView, it will solve the Problem!

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/widgets_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="2.0sp"
    tools:discard="@layout/unused2"
    tools:keep="@layout/l_used*_c,@layout/l_used_a,@layout/l_used_b*"
    tools:listitem="@layout/widget_item" />
```